# Python SqlAlchemy model instance with filter on join returns None type

Tags: python, database, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

My problem is to get model instance from join many to many tables and filter it by table1.id, and table2.some_field as a subquery or second filter.

For example I have models like so:

```
assoc = db.Table('table1_table2',
                            db.Column('table1_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('table1.id')),
                            db.Column('table2_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('table2.id')))

class Table1(db.Models):
   id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
   name = db.Column(db.String)

class Table2(db.Models):
   id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
   some_field = db.Column(db.Boolean)
   table1 = db.relationship('Table1', secondary=table1_table2)
```

Based on that code

```
    instance = db.session.query(Table1).\
        join(Table1.table1).\
        options(contains_eager(Table1.table1)).\
        filter(Table1.name == some_value).\
        filter(Table2.somefield == True).\
        first()
```

I received `Table1` model instance, but when `no relation occurs` (empty Table2 table), I'm receiving `None` object. How to receive `instance.table2 == []` in my case to get lazy loading working?

EDIT:
I changed a bit my sqlalchemy query like this:

```
instance = db.session.query(Table1). \
        outerjoin(table1_table2). \
        outerjoin(Table2, and_(Table2.id == table1_table2.c.table2_id, Table2.some_field = True)). \
        filter(Table1.name == some_value). \
        first()
```

Result of this query is closer to my expectations - when there is no relations, it returns empty list, but when there're several relations, it returns all relations, withour filtering in join condition.

Expected result:

```
>>>instance.table2

[<Table2 {id}:True>, <Table2 {id}:True>]
```

instead of:

```
>>>instance.table2

[<Table2 {id}:True>, <Table2 {id}:False>, <Table2 {id}:True>]
```

Edit2:
after some edits my final query looks like:

```
instance = db.session.query(Table1). \
        filter(Table1.name == some_value). \
        outerjoin(table1_table2). \
        outerjoin(Table2, and_(Table2.id == table1_table2.c.table2_id, Table2.some_field = True)). \
        options(contains_eager(Table1.table2)).\
        all()[0]
```

Comment: In short, use `outerjoin()` and move the `Table2` predicate to the ON clause. Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43858179/using-contains-eager-with-a-filter-but-without-filtering-out-parents-that-have-n

Comment: @IljaEverilä I edited my question. You'r approach fixed instance None type, but now it returns unfiltered table2.some_field.

Comment: You left out the `options(contains_eager(...))`, so you're reverting to the default behaviour in the new query.

Comment: @IljaEverilä With options(contains_eager(...)) inserted after joins, I'm receiving only one table2 instance; and with no relations I've againg None type of table1 instance

Comment: Overlooked your use of `first()`, which fetches the first **row** and the first row only, so receiving only 1 `Table2` instance is natural (it works by using `LIMIT 1` or equal). Instead use `all()` and extract the instance(s). Cannot reproduce the "with no relations I have `None` again".

Comment: After some edits and your help I managed to get this working. Thanks!

Comment: While I don't think selectinload nor subqueryload would allow filtered collections, I think they don't share the same behaviour / limitation in relation to using `first()`, but I'd have to check. Just something to keep in mind.